# Mojolicious test and plackup live run different

Tags: perl, mojolicious

sometimes when I run the test, I get the following.

```
# Inactivity timeout
```

[Mojo's documentation](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#EventSource_web_service) seems to recommend adding

```
Mojo::IOLoop->stream($self->tx->connection)->timeout(300);
```

however when I try adding this into the program I get this error on my `plackup` run instance

```
[fatal] Processing request failed: encountered object 'Can't call method "timeout" on an undefined value at ... line 22.
```

The likely reason this is timing out is due to a really slow HTTP request that's being run through a client library that uses LWP (though I've tried replacing LWP with [AnyEvent::HTTP::LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent%3a%3aHTTP%3a%3aLWP%3a%3aUserAgent) without any real code changes, just passing a different useragent)

I'm wondering what I might attempt to do to keep the connection running in the test, I don't seem to have a problem with live requests through chrome, or should I be looking in a different direction entirely?

Comment: mh.. maybe it´s the socket instance? try my $socket = $self->tx->connection);print (defined $socket) ? Mojo::IOLoop->stream($socket)->timeout(300) ? "socket undef"; - maybe it isolates your problem a lil more..

Comment: considering I asked this over a year ago, and am not longer employed where I had this problem... I'm not even sure that this problem would exist under a current mojo, give its rapid development.

Comment: haha thats wicked ;) havent seen that the question is soo old ;)